# How can i implement cache memory for display image?

Tags: android

I am developing an application,In My application,I am downloading lot of images from url using dom parsing.It is working fine.i wanna use cache memory for when i  see that image in first time ,that image downloaded from url,otherwise ie second time again see that image will not download from url,That time i will display that image from cache memory.how to implement in my application.

Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225817/how-to-load-internet-images-in-gridview-efficiently) question, which includes an answer for caching images downloaded from the Web.